# openarena crashes out of game when joining game

Tags: display, graphic-drivers

i am trying elementary os again. i would like to play openarena. i would like to commend you on the state of your display settings. i am able to choose primary display and the game will start on that display! and all i did was choose it! wonderful.

**There is a packaging error in the repository that causes the game to crash if you use the folder download version you are able to play**

now the problem is that i cannot actually target the correct monitor! when you start oa from repo installed version, it chooses the preferred monitor in settings and all is well until it crashes.

if you're using the folder version i cannot get it to choose the monitor attached to laptop. it draws the game on built-in no matter what.

how do you ask openarena to use the 2nd monitor?

thanks again for your help!